# Packer prepare error while building an image using VMware player as host

Tags: packer, vmware-player

I am new to packer.

I am trying to build a vmware VM using packer. I am using VMware player as host.

I set the variables and select the builders as following:

"builders": [
    {
      "boot_command": [" text net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 ks=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/ks.cfg"],
      "disk_size": "{{ user `disk_size` }}",
      "cpus": "{{ user `cpus` }}",
      "memory": "{{ user `memory` }}",
      "guest_os_type": "{{ user `guest_os_type` }}",
      "headless": "{{ user `headless` }}",
      "iso_checksum": "{{ user `iso_checksum` }}",
      "iso_checksum_type": "{{ user `iso_checksum_type` }}",
      "iso_url": "{{ user `iso_url` }}",
      "output_directory": "output-{{ user `vm_name` }}-cloud",
      "shutdown_command": "{{ user `shutdown_command` }}",
      "shutdown_timeout": "5m",
      "ssh_password": "{{ user `ssh_password` }}",
      "ssh_username": "{{ user `ssh_username` }}",
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "{{ user `ssh_wait_timeout` }}",
      "type": "vmware-iso",
      "vm_name": "{{ user `vm_name` }}"
        }
  ],

"variables": {
      "cpus": "2",
      "disk_size": "",
      "headless": "false",
      "iso_checksum": "",
      "iso_checksum_type": "sha256",
      "iso_url": "file://",
      "kickstart": "ks.cfg",
      "memory": "512",
      "shutdown_command": "shutdown -P now",
      "ssh_password": "packer",
      "ssh_username": "root",
      "ssh_wait_timeout" : "10000s",
      "guest_os_type": "rhel7-64",
      "vm_name": ""
  }

The error I am receiving is "Build 'vmware-iso' prepare failure: 1 error occurred:
    * unknown configuration key:" then it list all the parameters

After that I am receiving this --> and ctx data is map[interface {}]interface {}(nil)

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

After a I run the following commands:

"packer fix myfile.json > myfile-fixed.json"

"packer validate myfile-fixed.json"

issue resolved